# Microsoft JScript Runtime Error With FileZilla Client

Tags: javascript, notepad++, jscript, filezilla, adobe-brackets

I am usinf Filzilla Client to view/edit FTP files on my server I am able to open and edit HTMLn PHP, and  CSS Files using Notepad++ or Brackets Editor but on JavaScript files I am getting this error

[image]

the js Files icons also looks different than Notepad++ or Brackets Editor which are like bwlow

[image]

Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I have set "custom editor" & check "always use defualt editor" then working for me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmDLl.png

Comment: this solution works for me. thank you. 
although 1 picture is worth 1000 words, I think it would be nice to have a bit more explanation..

Answer (score -1):

By default the *View/Edit* command in FileZilla opens the file in an application associated with the file type. While you have the editor associated with `.php`/`.css`, you have a WSH runtime associated with `.js`, so the JavaScript files get executed.

You can override the default behavior by going to *Edit > Settings > File editing*.

[image]